# Python doesn't have access to internet but C# does

Tags: c#, python, proxy, firewall

I'm working a project that needs to download a certain webpage content, my code in C# works perfectly, however, it seems that Python can't get connected to the internet throwing an exception.

Perhaps it's because I'm working in a Corporate network and that's why Python might be blocked by Firewall. But, how about a C# code, why it works?

I'd like to emulate the Python code as C# WebClient behavior.

Thanks.

C# Code

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string str = wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.com");            
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Pythton Code

```
import urllib

link = "https://www.google.com"
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print myfile
```

Python Exception

> [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond

---

### [Edit 01]

[image]

### [Edit 02]

Tried `WebClient.Proxy = null`

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = null;
string str = wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.com");            
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Then I got this Exception. (`I also got this exception in a Java Program`)

> {"The operation has timed out"}

```
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at WebClientTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in <ProjectPath>\WebClientTest\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Copy pasting your Python code and running in Python 2 works fine for me.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network that might have a proxy server set up?

Comment: Maybe that's because C# WebClient can autodetect proxy if you have one (I may be wrong but as I remember it looks them up in the same place where Internet Explorer stores them). Try to set WebClient.Proxy to null and see if it then behaves the same as python script.

Comment: Thanks all. I have the config shown in the picture.

Comment: So as we see from screenshot, you indeed use proxy (with automatic configuration script). And failure with Proxy = null confirms this. So now you need to figure out how to set proxy in python.

Comment: Hey @Evk. Do you know how can I setup "automatic configuration script" in python or java?

Comment: Nope, as far as I know, python (urllib) also looks for proxy settings in registry by default (on windows), so not sure why it does not work. But my experience with python is quite limited.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evk.